# How to check network connectivity in background using Javascript(HTML) for mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, network-connection

I am creating a Hybrid mobile application and just want to check network connectivity so that to sync data  online. I am recommended NOT to use JQuery/JQuery Mobile.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you done so far? You can either ask the device if it has network connection (will be platform dependent) or just retrieve a small file from a remote server

Comment: Just try to do the sync, if you get an error queue it to do it later.

Comment: what about using the `navigator.onLine` ? you could use an eventListener to check for changes and then do what you want but you will need to show us some code you tried and we will gladly assist

Comment: @Torean, `navigator.onLine` isn't exactly reliable, each browser deals with it differently, and some only change it after some action (like following a link).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the events in javascript like this for online and offline .
      document.addEventListener("offline", yourCallbackFunction, false);
      document.addEventListener("online", yourCallbackFunction, false);

```
document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);

 function onOnline{
  //Handle the online event
 }
```

Comment: thanxs a lot Shreya Rawal

Comment: Glad to help :) @Anjali Patel